# prevent repeating data retrieved from SQL database by a select statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a database with a question table each question has a level attribute, topic, and the answers. I want to pick up randomly question in an ASP.net project but i don't want the same question to be repeated in the Details View.

This is the select statement:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [Question Number] AS Question_Number
       ,[Question Title] AS Question_Title
       ,[Answer 1] AS Answer_1
       ,[Answer 2] AS Answer_2
       ,[Answer 3] AS Answer_3
       ,QuizID
       ,Level
    FROM Question
    WHERE ( Level = 1 )
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax is obviously SQL Server.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  What is the "Details view"?  I, for one, don't understand the question.

Comment: the primary key is not a QuestionID so when I used OREDER BY NEWID() the same question was repeated

Comment: sounds like you have identical questions in the table question

Comment: Is Question_Number is primary key or unique in the table and the values for Question_Number & Question_Title are repeating?

Comment: no Question Title and Question Number are not repeating and the primary key is the question title

Comment: your query will never return 2 identical rows, so you must have identical questions. If that is not the case your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so you will get duplicate row until unless you have duplicate record in table. if you have then use DISTINCT to get unique record from table.

The basic syntax of DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicate records is as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,...columnN FROM table_name WHERE [condition]

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp